# Path based routing in AWS ALB to single host with multiple ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I want to create an ALB which should route my traffic based on path to different websites. For example.

example.com/apple/ should go to 8080

example.com/grapes/ should go to 8180

example.com/oranges/ should go to 8280

Could you please guide me, how can i achieve this.

What i have tried so far is below.

1. Create listener on port 80 and created different target groups for different port then in rules 80--->8080((If path /apples/) ),80--->8180(If path /grapes/)

But this approach is not working and traffic is only working for default route.

2. If i create listener for each port like 8080 --?8080(Target group) then my Load balancer URL would be like

LB:PORT/Path/

I do not want port in the URL.

Please help

Comment: Option 1 is correct.  For the path, did you specify *exactly* `/apple/` and does the URL (in the browser) contain *exactly* `/apple/` (including the trailing slash)?

Comment: Yes, the URL has the trailing slash.. example.com/apple/   this way.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to work with path based routing

- Create Target group  ( valid VPC, PORT, Proper health check )
- Add instance to the target group
- Go to LB and click on the existing listener
- Create new Rule and Add the new target group
- Verify Health check

As I see a similar question many times so posting screens shoot according to above steps.

[image]

[image]

Edit and add the instances
[image]

Go to AlB and select listener

[image]

Add rule and save

[image]

Comment: Adii if it is only one port the approach you said it correct..as I explained in the question if there are multiple ports on same server. Listiner is not forwarding the traffic to Target groups on 8080 or 8180 or anything it just forwarding it to default 80. I hope you have tested it before answeing it..!! Just wondering since I have created five web application Target groups but this seems not working ..

Comment: YEs I have tested and can guide you on other medium too if this is still not going to cofnigure from you

Comment: Adiii,please share the screenshot of the listners rules and target groups.. i am eager to know what i have missed

Comment: the last image is from listener rule